# Can you pass a type and enforce what type is passed in C#?

Tags: c#, types

I set up a method to pass a type as a parameter

```
private void SomeMethod(System.Type type)
    {
        //some stuff
    }
```

Is there a way to enforce the type so that you can only pass in types that inherit from a specific base class?

Comment: `void SomeMethod(BaseType obj)`, no?

Comment: He's not passing an object of some type - he's passing the type itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a lot of possibilities...

instance-based:

```
private void SomeMethod(object list) // total generic
```

becomes

```
private void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<object> list) // enumerable-generic
```

or

```
private void SomeMethod(List<object> list) // explicit list
```

OR with generic functions:

```
private void SomeMethod<T>() where T : MyType // << contraints
{
    var theType = typeof(T);
}
```

call that:

```
var xyz = SomeClass.SomeMethod<string>(); // for example
```

for more info about constraints:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: private void SomeMethod<T>() where T : MyType 
was exactly what I was looking for, I tried something similar but I'm new to generics so i didnt have the syntax right.

Answer (score 8):

Try making your function generic, and passing the type parameter in through the generic type parameter:

```
private void SomeMethod<T>() where T : U {
    Type type = typeof(T);
    // some stuff
}
```

You can use any type constraint listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

If it has to handle arbitrary type objects (e.g. when you don't have control over who calls the function), then you probably just have to use runtime assertions:

```
private void SomeMethod(System.Type type)
{
    if(!typeof(U).IsAssignableFrom(type)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("type must extend U!");
}
```

See also this question on [Type Restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025859/type-restriction).